# Issue Subclassing a Qlabel C++

Tags: c++, qt, intellisense, qtgui, qlabel

I am attempting to subclass a QLabel using a header file and I get the error on constructor

> IntelliSense: indirect nonvirtual base class is not allowed

```
class foo : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

    foo(QWidget* parent = 0) :  QWidget(parent)
    {

    }

    void mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent * event )
    {
        //Capture this
    }

};
```

Any suggestions why this is happening and how I can fix it ?

Comment: You need use QLabel, instead  QWidget in the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
foo(QWidget* parent = 0) :  QWidget(parent)
```

You are inheriting from **QLabel**, but you specify `QWidget` for the base. You should write this intead:

```
explicit foo(QWidget* parent = Q_NULLPTR) :  QLabel(parent)
//                                           ^^^^^^
```

Also, please use `explicit` for that constructor as well as `Q_NULL_PTR` or at least `NULL` instead of 0.

Comment: The last sentence, what's it for?

Comment: @Tay2510: 1) Avoid implicit conversion. 2) Use nullptr with C++11.